# how to install WIndows 8/10 on Dell Venue Pro (Uefi) after having damaged partitions

Tags: windows, installation, uefi, liveusb, dell-venue

My device is Dell Venue Pro 11 which came with Windows 8 x64 pre-installed on the SSD.

*Previous issues* ->

Firstly I installed Ubuntu on dual-boot in the same SSD: after doing that Windows stopped booting, i.e. I was only able to enter Ubuntu.

Secondly I tryed recovering my Windows partition by using Testdisk and other tools for fixing partitions, booted in live mode from a usb stick: after doing that my partition table seemed to be completely gone and so I couldn't enter nor Windows or Ubuntu.

Now I can only booting live operative systems from usb stick (I never tried using a cd). Some of them boot, some others don't, anyhow using a usb stick is the only way I may work on my tablet pc.

Now *I'm trying to reinstall Windows* ->

I purchased a license key and downloaded the ISO of the upgraded version (Windows 10 x64) which is still compatible with my hardware.
I put the ISO in the usb stick, which was configured in "multiboot" mode (I used Yumi for doing that).
I switch on the tablet pc and push twice the volume + button to enter the boot menu; I boot from the usb stick and then select the first option to install windows; I click "install".

*That's what I get* ->

the installation procedure seems to begin, I get the Windows 10 logo and then a blue screen appears; a window appears for a very short time and then the blue screen only remains; I cannot do any operation but moving the cursor only. 
(Exception: Once I got the window with the installation menu in the middle of the blue screen. But When I rebooted the issue recurred).

*Additional attempts ->*

I also launched Gparted live from usb stick and deleted the partition where the previous Windows was installed (the whole space in the SSD) and then tried installing Windows;

I also created a new NTFS partition with Gparted in the SSD by using the whole space in the SSD and then tried to install windows;

I also tried putting ISO in the usb stick by using other tools (unebootin, Rufus) and without the "multiboot" configuration;

I also tried using the Windows 8.1 x64 ISO instead than the Windows 10 pro x64;

I also tried changing the bios mode (legacy boot, Uefi, security mode enabled/disabled);

I also tried selecting the usb stick both from the Uefi menu and the legacy boot menu in the boot menu.

Given that, my problem is: How can I install Windows 10 x64 on a UEFI device from a Usb stick? Why I'm having these trouble (blue screen) in an apparently random way when I launch the installation?

Comment: Delete the partitions, boot to the installation disk and install Windows, it's that easy

Comment: I did it (I edited my question by inserting this additional step), but ...still...it didn't work.

Comment: What does the blue screen say?

Comment: @Seth nothing. I just get a completely blue screen where the cursor only can be moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue in this particular case by removing the sd card inserted into the device.

I didn't consider it might cause any trouble because it is still possible to choose the partition before installing Windows.
Firstly I removed the card, so as to have the usb card and the ssd only among the bootable devices; then I rebooted from the usb stick and selected the first option in the menu to enter Windows installation; in the next step I confirmed and then I got the configuration window in the middle of the blue screen (not just the blue screen), so I had full control of everything. I kept on by installing the operative system and well, now I got it!

A possible cause is the following: the sd card prevented the boot loader from recognizing the partition where Windows had to be installed; once I removed it, I only got two devices: the usb stick I was using for installing Windows and the ssd with the ntfs partition.

I summarize the whole procedure below ->

1 . I created a "multiboot" usb device by using Yumi and put the Windows 10 x64 ISO in there, previously downloaded after having purchased a license code;

2 . I inserted the usb stick into the Dell Venue Pro tablet and removed any other flash memory from it (in this case the sd card);

3 . I switched on my Dell Venue Pro 11 tablet and entered the Bios setup panel by double clicking on the volume + button after starting the device;

4 . I switched the Bios mode to "Legacy boot - secure mode disabled" and restarted;

5 . I booted from the usb stick previously inserted on;

6 . In the boot menu I selected the first option to install a Windows system;

7 . I confirmed I wanted to install Windows;

8 . I kept on installing Windows by following the steps shown in the configuration procedure.